# How to write R output with unequal length into excel

Tags: r, write.table

I have this R code to simulate time series data, the series have 5 colomns and 35 sub

```
N <- c(15L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 100L)
SD = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ^ 2
theta = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99)

res <- vector('list', length(N))
names(res) <- paste('N', N, sep = '_')

set.seed(123L)
for (i in seq_along(N)){
  res[[i]] <- vector('list', length(SD))
  names(res[[i]]) <- paste('SD', SD, sep = '_')

  ma <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N[i], ncol = length(theta)) 

  for (j in seq_along(SD)){
    wn <- rnorm(N[i], mean = 0, sd = SD[j])
    ma[1:2, ] <- wn[1:2]

    for (k in 3:N[i]){
      ma[k, ] <- wn[k - 1L] * theta + wn[k]
    }
    colnames(ma) <- paste('ma_theta', theta, sep = '_')
    res[[i]][[j]] <- ma
  }
}

res
```

** I EXPECT THIS**

```
v1  v2   v3  v4...v15  
1   4    3    1...1
2   6    3    2...2
3   8    3    12...5
4   4    4    8...5
5   6    4    4...5
6   8    4    0...5
7   4    5    2...5
8   6    5    1...2
9   8    5    2...2
10  11   12   13...2
11  12   13   14...4
8   6    5    1...4
9   8    5    2...4
10  11   12   13...4
11  12   13   14...4
```

I want to write `res` into any of the excel file. It could be .csv file.
I want `1` in one cell, `2` in one cell etc and not 12345 put together in a cell.

After then I write it to an excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res` is a nested `list` of `matrices`, we can `rbind` it after looping over the `list`

```
res1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))) 
str(res1)
# num [1:1075, 1:7] -0.56 -0.23 1.513 0.382 0.143 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:7] "ma_theta_0.2" "ma_theta_0.4" "ma_theta_0.6" "ma_theta_0.8" ...
```

Then, the `write.table` works as it is a single `matrix`

---

If we need to `cbind` the inner `list` elements, as the number of rows are different, an option is `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
out2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) 
      do.call(cbind.fill, c(as.data.frame(x), fill = NA))))
colnames(out2) <-  make.unique(rep(colnames(res[[1]][[1]]), length.out = ncol(out2)))
```

#### Update

If we need multiple data.frame output,  `cbind`  the `list` elements

```
res1 <- lapply(res, function(dat) do.call(cbind,  dat))
sapply(names(res1), function(nm) write.csv(res1[[nm]], 
      file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```

Comment: the rbind works well and the file is written to excel but I want the output to be arranged in columns

Comment: @DanielJames  Do you need `do.call(cbind, x)`  If that is the case, and your rows are different, use, `library(rowr); do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) do.call(cbind.fill, c(as.data.frame(x), fill = NA))))`

Comment: I observe that the 7 elements in each row are written in a cell. the problem is not in write procedure but the output.

Comment: @DanielJames Not exactly clear what you wanted `library(dplyr);out2 <- bind_rows(lapply(res, function(x) as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, t)))))`

Comment: I simply want each element of the 7 columns in separate columns. unlike what I have that 15 elements (that is supposed to be a row) are in a sell.-0.560475646552213 -0.23017748948328 1.51267281625247 0.382250054254401 0.143389413445861 1.74092253391547 0.803929203365858 -1.17287799340869 -0.939865098814833 -0.583032540478663 1.13494940341947 0.604630186545256 0.472734216005525 0.19083700606393 -0.5 this15 elements are in a cell.

Comment: @DanielJames  In the end, do you need a single data.frame or multiple

Comment: @DanielJames If you can update your post with few rows of the expected, then it might be useful,, thanks

Comment: @akrun e.g. if I take your first `list` element, `do.call(cbind, res[[1]])`, gives 35 columns and 15 rows

Comment: I need a single data.frame

Comment: @DanielJames  If you couldd update your post with first few lines of expected, it wouldn't take that much time instead of us going back and forth to understand

Comment: @DanielJames  When you say `want each element of the 7 columns in separate columns` Isn't that just transpose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206674/discussion-between-daniel-james-and-akrun).

Comment: `res1 <- lapply(res, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, t)))`  
`sapply(names(res1), function(nm) write.csv(res1[[nm]], 
                                           file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))` get it done

Comment: Can you please Transpose the result for me and give each column heading?
I am sorry to ask for this after which I rejected your offer to do so initially
I am sorry to ask for this after which I rejected your offer to do so initially
It becomes obvious to me after a thorough study of the result