# Write to Data Frame Then to .csv file in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv, write.table

I want the output of the bellow `R` code be written to `.csv` file.

```
N <- c(15L, 20L)
SD <- c(1, 2) ^ 2
phi = c(0.2, 0.4)

## generate all combos
all_combos <- expand.grid(N = N, SD = SD, phi = phi)

## create function
fx_arima <- function(n, SD, phi) {
  (arima.sim(n = n,
            model=list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 1, 0)),
            start.innov = 4.1,
            n.start = 1,
            rand.gen = function(n) rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = SD)))[-1]
}

## find arima for all combos using Map
Map(fx_arima, all_combos[["N"]], all_combos[["SD"]], all_combos[["phi"]])

## or :
set.seed(123L)
by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], 
   function(DF) {
     res = mapply(fx_arima, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
     colnames(res) = paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "_")
     res
   })
```

The above `R` code simulate `ARIMA(1,1,0)` with varying values of `N <- c(15L, 20L), SD <- c(1, 2) ^ 2, phi = c(0.2, 0.4)`. N=15 is printed in a matrix and N=20 is printed in another matrix all columns with column name. I want each matrix be writen in `datafram` and then written to .csv file that will be stored in my working directory.

**I EXPECT THIS**

```
v1  v2   v3  v4 
1   4    3    1
2   6    3    2
3   8    3    12
4   4    4    8
5   6    4    4
6   8    4    0
7   4    5    2
8   6    5    1
9   8    5    2
10  11   12   13
11  12   13   14
8   6    5    1
9   8    5    2
10  11   12   13
11  12   13   14
```

I tried what was done in [How to write R output with unequal length into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922709/how-to-write-r-output-with-unequal-length-into-excel)
 but couldn't get it

Comment: `Map(fx_arima, all_combos[["N"]], all_combos[["SD"]], all_combos[["phi"]])` returns a list of length 8. How do you want to write it in csv? Each list in different csv with one column? Or one combined csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could first, save the results to a list, `final.result`.

```
final.result <- by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], 
   function(DF) {
     res = mapply(fx_arima, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
     colnames(res) = paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "_")
     res
   })
```

Because the `N` group is in the name of the object and not in the column names, we can use a loop to append the `N` to the begining of the column names with `paste0`. Then we can write out with `write.table`.

```
for(i in seq_along(final.result)){
  group <- names(finalresult)[i]
  colnames(final.result[[i]]) <- paste0("N_",group,"_",colnames(final.result[[i]]))
  write.table(final.result[[i]],sep=",",file="test.csv",append = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In write.table(final.result[[i]], sep = ",", file = "~/test.csv",  :
  appending column names to file
2: In write.table(final.result[[i]], sep = ",", file = "~/test.csv",  :
  appending column names to file`

Comment: `sapply(names(final.result), function(nm) write.csv(final.result[[nm]], 
                                           file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))` helps

Comment: I think the `sapply` solution is better, I would not have arrived at that if you have not call `final.result` a name. please adopt that and let me give you the credit because I have been on it for a day.

Comment: I am very sorry to let you know that the warnings still persist and no result produced on Windows even after your update.